# Listen to Datetime stored in SQL server table constantly

Tags: c#, sql-server, api

I am working on back-end project that will serve mobile application.
The application will store some datetime fields in SQL server then it will notify the user on the each date.
The problem now is how to add listener on these fields to detect if the date is the current date .. I have two solutions:

1- Create windows service to listen on each new row and get the inserted date then convert it to seconds and creating timer that will decreasing those seconds .. and notify the user when the seconds = 0. I think this is a bad solution.

2- Create windows service to execute query every second on the database to select the row where the stored time equals now. I think this is worst.
So what is the best solution between them.
Or any other ideas.
thank you

Comment: How about read the database date one time and create a background job with that date? Hangfire is a good example to create background jobs in C#

Comment: @Linoy.M.Kunjappan thank you .. I think this will be the best solution .. I will work on it now :)

Comment: `Query Notifications` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SqlTableDependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

SqlTableDependency is a generic C# component used to receive notifications when the content of a specified database table change.

There's a nice article on it here: https://dzone.com/articles/receive-notifications-with-new-values-when-table-r

Comment: Thank you .. but this library is working on changes (Insert,Update,Delete) .. I want to get the dates that equal now on each second not on changes